# simple_settings.LazySettings raises "cannot import name 'get_cache' from 'django.core.cache'"

Tags: python-3.x, django

The following import fails only on my github actions workflow, but works on my local env:

```
     from simple_settings import LazySettings
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simple_settings/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .models import Settings
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simple_settings/models.py:2: in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'get_cache' from 'django.core.cache' (/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py)
```

Has anyone else encoutered this?

Here's the requirements also:

```
certifi==2022.12.7
chromedriver_autoinstaller==0.4.0
django_simple_settings==0.3.1
jira==3.4.1
openapi_core==0.16.5
pytest==7.2.0
pytest_schema==0.1.1
python_dateutil==2.8.2
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
selenium==4.8.2
simple_settings==1.2.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.13
```

Python 3.10, OS: Ubuntu-latest

Comment: i think there is function with name `get` not `get_cache` in `BaseCache`. can you try 
`from django.core.cache import cache` then 
`cache.get(key)`

Comment: Well its within the library simple_settings, which i install via pip, i guess i ll have to create a pr with the change on their repo
But still it makes no sense why is it working on my local env

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?